# Menu multi level in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web

I want to create ReactJS with menu like below.

when click to a menu in the left side, the sub menu appear at the right side.

anyone can help me how to do it, or at least the keyword relate to it.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please present a programming issue within stackoverflow, try to code this for yourself, search the web. If your stuck at a piece of code, feel free to post that question where you are stuck at.

Comment: But to not leave you in the dark. Search for 'multi level click menu'. You can maybe modify a existing dropdown menu.